# Move emails to a different folder based on date filter

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

I can't seem to find a way to easily move emails from Sent folder to some other folder based on a date filter. I know that You can create rules for Inbox folder, but for some other folder I did not find a way to do it.

I can do a search inside a folder, and select items currently shown (click select all) and perform move action, but this works only for items loaded to browser, not all search results.

Does anybody have a better way to move a LOT of emails (without using desktop version of Outlook) ? For example all emails sent before 2020 to a subfolder called 2020.

Comment: If you use the same approach as in [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/171156) can you move "all" the messages?

Comment: I can, but I wanted to avoid manual selection since I have around 50k messages to group by folders and a few more folders to which I need to do the same. I was hoping there is some automated solution.